# Convert string to an integer using a given base

Tags: c++, integer

What is the `C++` equivalent of the following `Java` line of code

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("0010011110", 2);
```

Comment: (Careful with the tags and titles; Java users likely don't care :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) to parse an integer in base 2:

```
const char *binStr = "0010011110";
char *endPtr;
int x = strtol(binStr, &endPtr, 2);
cout << x << endl; // prints 158
```

Here is a [link to a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/JwCyNl).

Answer (score 7):

[std::stoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (since C++11):

```
int x = std::stoi("0010011110", nullptr, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap up [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) as `parseInt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parseInt(const std::string& s, int base) {
    return (int) strtol(s.c_str(), null, base);
}

int x = parseInt("0010011110", 2);
```

Comment: this is pure C (.h, NULL, (int)...) OP asked for C++

Comment: It doesn't mean that he can't call C function

Comment: It means C++ coding style at last.

Comment: what do you prefer to make parseInt more C++ like? Now I pass string ref as argument, more c++ like? :D

Comment: you should include C headers in C++ as `#include <cstdlib>` so you can use the functions from `std::` namespace, like `std::strtol`, C casting is bad style, C++ advocates his own casts. Use `nullptr` if possible, instead of NULL...

Comment: so you just assume C++11 is valid everywhere now?

Comment: changing arg from `const char *` to `const std::string &` is not signal of C++ style.

Answer (score 0):

[atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) or better yet [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

```
long x = strtol("0010011110",nullptr, 2);
```